# tap event in the Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I find a problem that when I "tap" or "click" an element it will be trigger twice in my recent project.For example:

```
......

<div id='target'></div>   
......


<script>

  $('#target').click(function(){alert('touched!')});

</script>
```

and then it will alert "touched" twice!!!!

I thought if I use a gesture library I could fix it so I try Hammer.js.But it seems that the problem still can't be fixed.I am so confused by this and really hope someone could give me some advice.Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#target').click(function(){alert('touched!')});
    });
    </script>
```

seee
[**Js Fillde**](http://jsfiddle.net/ThYLw/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#target').unbind('click');
      $('#target').bind('click',function(event){
          alert('touched!')
      });
});
```

Sometimes , the event firing happens multiple times because it is bound multiple times. Try [**unbind**](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) before [**bind**](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Answer (score 1):

When doing project using phonegap I had a similar problem( I think the problem was mostly on android jelly bean devices). So this what I did:

```
var isEvent = false;

$(document).ready(function(){

 $(element).click(function(){
    if(!isEvent){
      isEvent = true;
      doSomething();
    }
    setTimeout(function(){isEvent=false;},50); // time in ms should be set according to your needs
 });
});
```

At the time this was the only solution that worked 100%

Comment: I try your code on my android and it fails again!!!! I really don't know how to fix it.....

Answer (score 1):

in modern browsers you simply can use touchstart and touchend

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
  alert('touch started at ' + Date.now() );
}, false);
document.addEventListener('touchend', function(){
  alert( 'touch ended at ' + Date.now() );
});
```

you can test touch events in chrome developer tools by setting a touch device. dont know if other browsers support this too

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', 'page_id', function(){
     $('#target').click(function(){alert('touched!')});
});
```